# Why repaint() statement executes after next statement

Tags: java, paintcomponent, repaint

I want to add 1 in the value of x (piece.x) after repainting component but it repaints after adding 1 in x

What i actually need is to to paint component with the given value (var) and to change value of piece.x after repainting component

```
piece.x = var;
repaint();
piece.x += 1
```

**Added**

I have a box(rectangle) which moves right & left (on x axis) every second(which requires repainting) but i want to change the position(value of x-axis) of that box after repainting

simply repaints the box with the existing value of x and then change its value but it changes first and then repaints

Thanks !

Comment: try to call validate() before repaint. but in any cast it bad idea to hope that changed value related to painting will not be repainted accidently

Comment: Trying to synchronize something with the paint mechanism is in most cases a sign for a design flaw. You should describe in more detail what you actually want to *achieve*.

Comment: @Marco13 just to change the value of x after repainting

Comment: If you think that this is enough information, I encourage you to read more questions here on stackoverflow, and see how often you think "Dude, how is someone supposed to answer a question *that* vague?". It's difficult.

Comment: @Marco13 Sir I added explanation. I hope you'll understand

Answer (score 0):

Why: Repaint happens in a separate thread and only schedules repainting. `JComponent.paintImmediately(...);` can be used to force a repaint without scheduling it in the back of the paint queue.

```
piece.x = var; // This happens immediately
repaint(); // This schedules the repaint in a separate thread
piece.x += 1 // This isn't guaranteed to happen before or after the repaint
```

---

Some people have used time delays to try and wait for the repaint to finish before continuing their execution.

It's probably better to evaluate why you need to only increment the variable after the repaint has finished and see if you can change your design/logic to accommodate the repainting happening in a separate thread.

Comment: There's not guarantee on how long it will take or how soon it will finish. So sleeping your Thread is just guessing at how long it may take. So you may or may not wait long enough.

Answer (score -1):

As Andrew pointed out, the reason of *why* the repainting happens after changing the x-value is simple: The `repaint()` call does not cause the contents to be painted immediately. It only tells the windowing system to repaint the component as soon as possible. But this may happen a few milliseconds later, on a different thread.

For more details, one can have a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html , for example.

Based on the description of the actual goal, although it is still vague:

> I have a box(rectangle) which moves right & left (on x axis) every second(which requires repainting) but i want to change the position(value of x-axis) of that box after repainting

It is still not clear why the x-value should change *after* repainting. What is going to happen after the x-value has changed? Why should it not be painted on the position that it actually *has* when it is painted?

However, the last question may already lead to a potential answer: When you want to differentiate between a "real" position and a "painting" position, then you could model this explicitly and clearly: In addition to the current `x` variable, the class could have a field that may be called `paintX`. It is the position where the box should be painted, regardless of the value that `x` currently has.

Of course, this sounds fiddly, and the reason of why you may have to do this is that the model and the view are not clearly separated. But in any case, keep in mind that even *if* you could force the object to be painted and change the x-value *after* the object was painted, you have to consider that it may then be painted *again*, at the new x-position. You can't prevent the window from being repainted, and this is beyond your control.

Comment: I'm looking forward to see the "useful" answer that the downvoter is hopefully posting soon.